# Comparador PHP " != "

Tags: php, comparação

Estou tendo uma certa dificuldade com o seguinte código;

```
//Verifica Se o usuario esta cadastrado no Codelist 
$query = "select trim(loginid) loginid from yfs_user where loginid = '$USER'";
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $query);

db2_execute($stmt, array(10));

while (db2_fetch_row($stmt)) {
    $name = db2_result($stmt, 0);
        if ($name != $USER)
    {
        echo "<h1>Usuário $name, não encontrado.</h1>";
        die ;
    }
}
```

Então, explicando, esse código é parte de uma função *PHP* que criei para verificar se o usuário existe na base de dados *DB2*. Dentro do *While*, declaro a variável `$name` e verifico ela no `if ($name != $USER)` com o comparador `!=`, ou seja, se o *input* for diferente do que está no banco, então o código exibe uma mensagem e é encerrado com a função `die()`.

Porém, o que acontece é o oposto, ele passa direto por essa função e não me apresenta a mensagem *Usuário `$name` não encontrado*.

Segue o código inteiro, se puderem me dar uma luz.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>RETORNO DE CODELIST</title>
        <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<?php

    //Valida se campo usuario ou senha estao vazios
    //if (empty($_POST['user']) or empty($_POST['passwd']))
    //    {
               // echo "<h1><h1><br />";
   //     }

    //Variaveis
    $USER = strtolower(trim($_POST['user']));
    //$PASS = trim($_POST['passwd']);
    $USER2 = $USER{0};



//------------------------------------------------------------
//Parâmetros de Banco de Dados
$hostname = '#####';
$port = #####;
$user = '####';
$password = '#####';
$database = '#####';

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

//Verifica Se o usuario esta cadastrado no Codelist 
$query = "select trim(loginid) loginid from yfs_user where loginid = '$USER'";
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $query);

db2_execute($stmt, array(10));

while (db2_fetch_row($stmt)) {
    $name = db2_result($stmt, 0);
        if ($name != $USER)
    {
        echo "<h1>Usuário $name, não encontrado.</h1>";
        die ;
    }
}




                //Contador para Nao dar problema em sobrescrever arquivos
                $ARQUIVO = "/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/cont_delete.hits";
                $HANDLE = fopen($ARQUIVO, 'r+'); // Da Permissao para ler o Arquivo
                $DATA = fread($HANDLE, 512); // Obtem a contagem do Arquivo
                $CONTADOR = $DATA + 1; //Adiciona +1 no Arquivo
                fseek($HANDLE,0); // O Ponteiro Volta para o comeco do arquivo
                fwrite($HANDLE,$CONTADOR); //Salva o valor da variavel CONTADOR no arquivo
                fclose($HANDLE); // Fecha Arquivo

                //Escreve os XML dentro no /tmp/usuario.bp
                file_put_contents("/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/usuario_deletado_$CONTADOR.bp", "<INFO>\n");
                file_put_contents("/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/usuario_deletado_$CONTADOR.bp", "<DADO><NAME>$USER</NAME></DADO>\n",FILE_APPEND);
                file_put_contents("/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/usuario_deletado_$CONTADOR.bp", "</INFO>\n",FILE_APPEND);

                // Executa Shell Script para excluir Usuario
                shell_exec("/var/www/cgi-bin/delete_user_homol_santa.sh '$CONTADOR' 1> /tmp/result_delete.txt 2> /tmp/erro_delete.txt");

                ?>
                <body>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href='../index2.php'">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alerta !!!</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <?php echo "<h1>Usuário $name excluido !!</h1>"; ?>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            $('#myModal').modal('show');

                        });
                    </script>

                </body>
                <?php

?>
```

Comment: Tenta criar um $num_rows = db_num_rows($stmt); e um if($num_rows){ echo "usuario existe"; }

Comment: tentei, não deu certo, até dei uma olhada na documentação do php referente ao num_rows, mas não consegui obter o resultado.

Comment: Boa tarde Wilton, tem como espelhar os dados que estão enviados para $USER e as que vem na $name (Postar para nós)? tenta da Print nela nas tela e ver se vem os dados correto, se tiver XDebug facilita achar o erro.

Comment: Boa tarde Paulo, sou novato no PHP, estou estudando bastante sobre, me desculpe a ignorância, mas nao sei fazer isso ainda, tem algum tutorial para me indicar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui resolver da seguinte forma, caso ajude alguém com o mesmo problema que o meu !!!

```
<?php

    //Valida se campo usuario ou senha estao vazios
    if (empty($_POST['user']))
        {       
                echo "<h1>Campos Usuàrio Vazio<h1><br />";
                exit;
        }

    //Variaveis
    $USER = strtolower(trim($_POST['user']));


//------------------------------------------------------------
//Parâmetros de Banco de Dados
$hostname = '#####';
$port = ####;
$user = '#####';
$password = '#####';
$database = '#####';

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

//Verifica Se o usuario esta cadastrado no Codelist 
$query = "select trim(loginid) loginid from yfs_user where loginid = '$USER'";
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $query);

db2_execute($stmt, array(10));

while (db2_fetch_row($stmt)) {
    $name = db2_result($stmt, 0);
        if ($name == $USER)
    {echo "Usuário $name, Excluido";}


                //Contador para Nao dar problema em sobrescrever arquivos
                $ARQUIVO = "/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/cont_delete.hits";
                $HANDLE = fopen($ARQUIVO, 'r+'); // Da Permissao para ler o Arquivo
                $DATA = fread($HANDLE, 512); // Obtem a contagem do Arquivo
                $CONTADOR = $DATA + 1; //Adiciona +1 no Arquivo
                fseek($HANDLE,0); // O Ponteiro Volta para o comeco do arquivo
                fwrite($HANDLE,$CONTADOR); //Salva o valor da variavel CONTADOR no arquivo
                fclose($HANDLE); // Fecha Arquivo

                //Escreve os XML dentro no /tmp/usuario.bp
                file_put_contents("/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/usuario_deletado_$CONTADOR.bp", "<INFO>\n");
                file_put_contents("/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/usuario_deletado_$CONTADOR.bp", "<DADO><NAME>$USER</NAME></DADO>\n",FILE_APPEND);
                file_put_contents("/usr/local/html/santacruz_homol/usuario_deletado_$CONTADOR.bp", "</INFO>\n",FILE_APPEND);

                // Executa Shell Script para Inserir Usuario
                shell_exec("/var/www/cgi-bin/delete_user_homol_santa.sh '$CONTADOR' 1> /tmp/result_delete.txt 2> /tmp/erro_delete.txt");
                die;
}               

        echo "<h1>Usuàrio $USER não encontrado!!!'</h1><br />";



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é melhor fazer, em vez de

```
while (db2_fetch_row($stmt)) {
    $name = db2_result($stmt, 0);
    if ($name != $USER)
    {
        echo "<h1>Usuário $name, não encontrado.</h1>";
        die ;
    }
}
```

fazer assim, já que a query procura pelo usuário $USER na tabela,

```
$query = "select trim(loginid) loginid from yfs_user where loginid = '$USER'";
```

, ou seja a minha sugestão é:

```
if (db2_num_rows($stmt) == 0)
{
    echo "<h1>Usuário $USER não encontrado.</h1>";
    die();
}
```

?

Comment: Oi Marcelo, também deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda, ainda estou estudando php, então são erros meio bobos, mas valeu pela disponibilidade !!!!